# Mysql get recent rows by date for each specific group

Tags: mysql, database

i have Table (afk_map_data):

```
id map_id state_id measures_id value created_date
```

the question is >> i want to get only the latest rows for measures_id value by the recent created_date

i have tried many solutions i tried many things but it was stupid, i post this select statement to be my question clear

```
 SELECT  md.id,md.measures_id,md.value,md.created_date FROM afk_map_data md     
 WHERE  
 md.map_id = 1 
 AND md.state_id = 2
 AND md.measures_id = 4  


the result was :

id   measures_id    value  created_date
1           4        777    2016-07-03  
2           4        888    2016-07-03
3           4        999    2016-07-02
4           4        555    2016-07-02

the result that i want is : 

id   measures_id    value  created_date
1           4        777    2016-07-03  
2           4        888    2016-07-03

Thanks a lot ..
```

Comment: where the stateid comes from

Comment: How do you define "recent created date"? Use < or > operator to exclude all old entries. I am not really sure if I understand completely what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry guys for my bad question all what i want is to  clear the question ... thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **MAX Condition** on Date Column

```
 Select TT.id,T.measures_id,TT.value,T.d from afk_map_data TT
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  measures_id,MAX(created_date)d FROM afk_map_data
        GROUP BY measures_id )T
        ON  T.d = TT.created_date
WHERE  
 TT.map_id = 1 
 AND TT.state_id = 2
 AND TT.measures_id = 4
```